# VBA SQL: Syntax Error in From Clause, Double Inner Join with Password

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, syntax-error

I'm reasonably new to SQL and I'm trying to create a string that collects the following:

- Code from [Catalogue Info] as c
- Description from [Product Information] as p
- Weight from p
- PPB from p
- CP-UK from p
- CP-EU from p
- 1 from an external password protected database C:\mypath\db.accdb as
  pl

The code below keeps giving me a **Syntax error in From clause**. I'm assuming this is something to do with my brackets around the INNER JOINS but I'm not sure.

This code worked perfectly fine before adding in the second INNER JOIN clause (external DB), My WHERE & ORDER BY clauses work fine.

```
                sqlProd = "SELECT c.Code," _
            & " p.Description, p.weight, p.[Pack Size], p.PPB, p.[CP-UK], p.[CP-EU]," _
            & " pl.1" _
            & " FROM ([Catalogue Info] c" _
            & " INNER JOIN [Product Information] p" _
                & " on c.code = p.code)" _
            & " INNER JOIN [;database=C:\mypath\db.accdb;PWD=password123].table_name pl" _
                & " on c.code = pl.code" _
            & " WHERE c.Sub_Cat_1 = '" & rstSub1!Sub_Cat_1 & "'" _
            & " AND c.Sub_Cat_2 = '" & rstSub2!Sub_Cat_2 & "'" _
            & " ORDER BY c.Page ASC, c.Page_Position ASC;"
```

Any thoughts?

Access 2016, Excel 2016, Windows 10

Thanks!
Dom

Comment: Try using `as` for the table aliases:  `FROM ([Catalogue Info] as c`.

Comment: have you tried to build this query in Access itself? this might be the easiest way to find the right syntax.  Also, I don't think you need the brackets after from "(" . Try ommiting them?

Comment: I'm using Excel as the front-end for a price list manager, the code above is triggered by user input and gets the product information and prices from Access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a solution to this - it wasn't the bracketing, it was the password I was using.

The password I was using (not in original question) used special characters **(#>`{(=** which seemed to be giving the syntax error. I changed the password in my Access Database to letters/numbers only and the original code works fine.

Hope this helps anyone else out. Final code:

```
sqlProd = "SELECT c.Code," _
        & " p.Description, p.weight, p.[Pack Size], p.PPB, p.[CP-UK], p.[CP-EU]," _
        & " pl.[1]" _
        & " FROM [Catalogue Info] as c" _
        & " INNER JOIN [Product Information] as p" _
        & " on c.code = p.code" _
        & " INNER JOIN [;database=C:\mypath\db.accdb;PWD=password123].table_name as pl" _
        & " on c.code = pl.code" _
        & " WHERE c.Sub_Cat_1 = '" & rstSub1!Sub_Cat_1 & "'" _
        & " AND c.Sub_Cat_2 = '" & rstSub2!Sub_Cat_2 & "'" _
        & " ORDER BY c.Page ASC, c.Page_Position ASC;"
```

Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work, as I think you have unnecessary brackets around part of your `FROM` clause:

```
sqlProd = "SELECT c.Code," _
            & " p.Description, p.weight, p.[Pack Size], p.PPB, p.[CP-UK], p.[CP-EU]," _
            & " pl.1" _
            & " FROM [Catalogue Info] c" _
            & " INNER JOIN [Product Information] p" _
            & " on c.code = p.code" _
            & " INNER JOIN [;database=C:\mypath\db.accdb;PWD=password123].table_name pl" _
            & " on c.code = pl.code" _
            & " WHERE c.Sub_Cat_1 = '" & rstSub1!Sub_Cat_1 & "'" _
            & " AND c.Sub_Cat_2 = '" & rstSub2!Sub_Cat_2 & "'" _
            & " ORDER BY c.Page ASC, c.Page_Position ASC;"
```

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't working either, I'm getting a **missing operator** syntax error with this. Could it be the password that I'm using? It includes special characters (#>`{(=

Comment: That's possible, perhaps try enclosing the password in quotes? I must admit, I've never used the syntax you're using to join to a table in an Access DB, sorry.